# Arrays y bucles

Tags: javascript

soy muy novato en javascript y por ahora estoy practicando con arrays y bucles pero estoy trabado en una tontería que no se como resolver.

Estoy tratando de que por X numero de veces que coloque el usuario se haga una iteracion y añada dos valores por separado a un array, el problema está en que siempre en el indice 1 de valor que introduje en array lo añade como otro array dentro del array, es una locura.

Por ejemplo despues del codigo me queda algo así:

array1 [ Indice0:[ "valor0",[array2] ] ,Indice1: [valor0,[array3] ]

Algo así jaja, de todas maneras vean la consola al ejecutar la funcion "mostrarMateria" despues de haber puesto valores al array "materiasTotales" con la funcion "crearMateria", se darán cuenta de esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que esta señalado con la flecha es lo que no debería suceder.

```
let materiasTotales = [];

function crearMateria (materia){
    materia = prompt("Cuantas materias quieres crear?");
    if (materia > 3) {
        return alert("Sólo puedes crear un máximo de 3 materias");
    }else{
        for (i = 0; i < materia; i++) {
        materiasTotales[i] = [prompt(`Nombre de la materia Nº${i+1}`)]
        materiasTotales[i][1] = [prompt(`Nombre del profesor de la materia ${materiasTotales[i]}`)]
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < materia; i++) {
        console.log(`Materia registrada: ${materiasTotales[i][0]} Profesor: ${materiasTotales[i][1]}`);
    }
    alert(`Materias creadas exitosamente.`);
}

function mostrarMateria(materia){
    console.log(materiasTotales);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si te refieres a que el nombre de el profesor se guarda como una lista,es por que estas diciendo que las materias `materias[indice][1] = [nombre_profesor]` cuando
`materias[indice][1] = nombre_profesor` lo guardaria añadiendolo a el array

si ha esto te refieres espero que te sirva :D yo tampoco se mucho de javascript pero tengo esperiencia en lenguajes parecidos y si es a eso a lo que te refieres es esa linea la que genera el problema

Comment: por que a definir el indice 1 de un array como otro array hace [a,[b]] cuando el resultado esperado es [a,b]

Comment: este seria el resultado :
Array(1)
0: (2) ['mates', 'gorda']
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
diciendo que quiero crear 1 asignatura que es mates y que la da "gorda"

Comment: Era exactamente lo que decias! al colocar los corchetes guarda el valor como array, con razón tuve tantos errores en otros codigos que traté de hacer jaja, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Mira, te explico un poquito de los arrays:

Un array es una "lista" en la que puedes guardar varios valores, por ejemplo:

```
let frutas = ["Manzana", "Naranja"];
```

esto te mostraría una lista de 2 frutas.
Bien, ahora:

Tambien podemos guardar UN ARRAY dentro de UN ARRAY.
Esto es util cuando quieres guardar información como la de tu caso.
necesitas guardar materias, y podrías hacerlo así:

```
let materias = ["Mate", "Español"];
```

En ambos ejemplos que te doy, el primer valor se guarda en el indice 0 y el segundo en el indice 1.

Ahora, regresando a tu ejemplo.
El problema es que necesitas también el nombre del profesor.

Entonces, en el indice 0 necesitarías guardar 2 valores, no solo uno.

para poder conseguir esto solo hay que hacer una pequeña modificación a tu código:
y eso es agregarle `[0]` cuando pides el nombre de la materia

```
let materiasTotales = [];

function crearMateria (materia){
    materia = prompt("Cuantas materias quieres crear?");
    if (materia > 3) {
        return alert("Sólo puedes crear un máximo de 3 materias");
    }else{
        for (i = 0; i < materia; i++) {
        materiasTotales[i][0] = [prompt(`Nombre de la materia Nº${i+1}`)]
        materiasTotales[i][1] = [prompt(`Nombre del profesor de la materia ${materiasTotales[i]}`)]
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < materia; i++) {
        console.log(`Materia registrada: ${materiasTotales[i][0]} Profesor: ${materiasTotales[i][1]}`);
    }
    alert(`Materias creadas exitosamente.`);
}

function mostrarMateria(materia){
    console.log(materiasTotales);
}
```

de esta forma estás guardando un arreglo en la pocision 0, donde `materiasTotales[0] = "Nombre de la materia", "Nombre del profesor"`

si quieres solo la información de las materias, entonces:
`materiasTotales[0][0] = "nombre de la materia"`

o bien:
`materiasTotales[0][1] = "Nombre del profesor"`

Espero que te ayude!

Comment: Sabes yo también aplique esa lógica y coloqué el [0] en la parte del nombre de la materia, sin embargo me tiraba este error en consola: 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0')
    at crearMateria (cofla3.js:15)

Comment: Y sinceramente quedé un poco desconcertado porque viendo detalladamente no le pude encontrar la logica a ese error.

Comment: Ups, es porque el arreglo materiasTotales no está definido como un Array de arrays. Definelo así y no te debería dar errores